# Firebase Node.js- onAuthStateChanged() : How to redirect to different page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

As the onAuthStateChanged() function in Firebase does not accept any **res/req** parameters, nor does **window.location** work on Node.js (because it is server-side code), how do I redirect to another page after auth state changes?

For reference what I had was:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser=>{
    if(user){
         window.location = "/profile";   
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you writing code for the browser or for node.js?  They're completely different environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're using the client side Firebase SDK. If you're developing inside of Node you'll have to use the Admin SDK. I believe it gives you more control over authentication.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/

What you're trying to do would work well on the client but doing it on the server would require a completely different approach. One might be using a Cloud Function to have the user logout. You could handle the session manually and redirect as needed.

However, The code you're writing now is better suited to doing this over on the client.

Comment: Wow I did not know about this :( . Thank you for responding!